# MVVM - Update StatusBar from various views

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, mvvm, viewmodel

I am putting my first MVVM project together. I have a StatusBar that will be updated from various views (UserControls) from within the application. Each view will have its own DataContext. My original thought was to create a ViewModelBase class which implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and also contained a public property to bind the the text of my StatusBar to. All other ViewModels within the application would then inherit the ViewModelBase class. Of course, this does not work. How can I accomplish this? I am not using MVVM Light or any other frameworks and I am programming in vb.net. Thanks in advance.

Update - Below is the translation of what Garry proposed in the 2nd answer, I am still unable to modify the status text from the MainViewModel?? Anyone see a problem with the vb translation of his c# code? This MVVM transition is causing major hair loss!!

[image]

ViewModelBase.vb

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ViewModelBase
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

End Class
```

StatusViewModel.vb

```
Public Interface IStatusBarViewModel
    Property StatusBarText() As String
End Interface

Public Class StatusBarViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase
    Implements IStatusBarViewModel

    Private _statusBarText As String
    Public Property StatusBarText As String Implements IStatusBarViewModel.StatusBarText
        Get
            Return _statusBarText
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If value <> _statusBarText Then
                _statusBarText = value
                OnPropertyChanged("StatusBarText")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

MainViewModel.vb

```
Public Class MainViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase

    Private ReadOnly _statusBarViewModel As IStatusBarViewModel
    Public Sub New(statusBarViewModel As IStatusBarViewModel)
        _statusBarViewModel = statusBarViewModel
        _statusBarViewModel.StatusBarText = "Test"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Status.xaml (UserControl)

```
<StatusBar DataContext="{Binding StatusViewModel}">
...
<w:StdTextBlock Text="{Binding StatusText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Application.xaml.vb

```
Class Application

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStartup(e As System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
        Dim iStatusBarViewModel As IStatusBarViewModel = New StatusBarViewModel()
        Dim mainViewModel As New MainViewModel(iStatusBarViewModel)
        Dim mainWindow As New MainWindow() With { _
            .DataContext = mainViewModel _
        }
        mainWindow.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GlobalStatusBarTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:Status Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Are the various VM's all contributing to the same elements in the SB?  Or does each VM have its own real estate on the SB?

Comment: They are all contributing to the same elements. One TextBlock and one ProgressBar.

Comment: That's fine.  Also are you using Prism?  It would be really easy with the event aggregator!

Comment: No, I am not using any frameworks. This is a pretty small application and I really didn't want the overhead. Also, it seems that most of the frameworks that I have looked at are written in C#, the other developer that I am working with only works in vb.

Comment: I don't know VB, but if you can add the status bar's ViewModel to the constructor of all the other ViewModels, then each VM could access it.  You could use that approach as an 'injection strategy'

Comment: @GarryVass, would it be possible to post a simple example of your suggestion in c#?

Comment: @GarryVass, I used to work with c# quite a bit with ASP.NET so yes, I'm hoping it will be beneficial. :) The developer I work with is strictly vb so all projects that we work on together are written in vb. We are both trying to transition into MVVM and WPF. I really appreciate your time!

Comment: To be fair, status bar implementation as a User Control and the Xaml for your main window wasn't in the
original question and it actually changes the problem space. But no matter, I have the C# code working by
adding a User Control like yours and two dependency properties on the main window. The VM's I posted don't
need changing. And the overall strategy of manual injection is intact also. It's just a matter of the dependency
properties and populating them in the app.cs file. The coding takes about 15 minutes.  When you're back from holiday shout and I'll repost for you.

Comment: @GarryVass, I blinked and my holiday is over... I'm hoping that your offer still stands as I am still very much interested in getting this resolved. Regarding the use of the UserControls, I apologize for not making this clear from the beginning.

Comment: I restored my answer.  Check if you're ok with it, or if you need to post another question about user controls and let me know.  Otherwise hope you enjoyed your hols...

Comment: @GarryVass, I do not see any differences, were there any adjustments made to accommodate the use of UserControls?

Comment: I was catching up on where we were.  Have you opened a new question?  Or re-scoped this one?

Comment: @GarryVass, I have updated the question. Maybe I am going about things the wrong way but my intention was to break the "MainWindow" down into separate views based on functionality. Each view would be a UserControl in order to keep from cluttering up the xaml of the MainWindow. Each view would have its own ViewModel/DataContext however, certain data will need to be shared (such as the statusbar text) between all views.

Comment: I added another answer using dependency properties on the main shell.  It works fine and checks out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin, take your main window, the application shell, and change it to something like this...

```
    <DockPanel>
        <sample:StatusBarControl DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="StatusBarRegion"/> 
        <sample:MainContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="MainContentRegion"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

This partitions the shell into regions much like the Prism Region Manager.  Note that the 'content' is now a user control, along with any other views you want to place in that region.  Note also that the status bar has a region, but will not change its view or view model.

In the code behind of your shell, place two dependency properties like this...

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        #region MainContentDp (DependencyProperty)
        public object MainContentDp
        {
            get { return GetValue(MainContentDpProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MainContentDpProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MainContentDpProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MainContentDp", typeof(object), typeof(MainWindow),
              new PropertyMetadata(OnMainContentDpChanged));
        private static void OnMainContentDpChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow = d as MainWindow;
            if (mainWindow != null)
            {
                mainWindow.MainContentRegion.DataContext = e.NewValue;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region StatusBarDp (DependencyProperty)
        public object StatusBarDp
        {
            get { return GetValue(StatusBarDpProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StatusBarDpProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusBarDpProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("StatusBarDp", typeof(object), typeof(MainWindow),
              new PropertyMetadata(OnStatusBarDpChanged));
        private static void OnStatusBarDpChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow = d as MainWindow;
            if (mainWindow != null)
            {
                mainWindow.StatusBarRegion.DataContext = e.NewValue;
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

These dependency properties are substitutes for the Prism Region Manager.  Each Dependency Property sets the data context of its associated region.  In your case, you want to change the MainContentDp to switch back and forth between view models.

In the app.xaml.cs file, you can override the start up method to look like this...

```
public partial class App 
{
    protected override void OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        IStatusBarViewModel iStatusBarViewModel = new StatusBarViewModel();
        MainViewModel mainViewModel = new MainViewModel(iStatusBarViewModel);
        OtherViewModel otherViewModel = new OtherViewModel(iStatusBarViewModel);
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow
            {
                StatusBarDp = iStatusBarViewModel, 
                MainContentDp = mainViewModel
            };
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

This code creates the shell and assigns the two Dependency Properties, which in turn will populate the regions with their respective view models.

A view model would look like this...

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }
    private readonly IStatusBarViewModel _statusBarViewModel;
    public MainViewModel(IStatusBarViewModel statusBarViewModel)
    {
        _statusBarViewModel = statusBarViewModel;
        ClickCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteClickCommand, CanExecuteClickCommand);
    }
    private void ExecuteClickCommand(object obj)
    {
        _statusBarViewModel.StatusBarText = "Updating the db";
    }
    private bool CanExecuteClickCommand(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public void DoSomethingVeryImportant()
    {
        _statusBarViewModel.StatusBarText = "Starting some work";
        // do some work here
        _statusBarViewModel.StatusBarText = "Done doing some work";
    }
}
```

And another view model...

```
public class OtherViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IStatusBarViewModel _statusBarViewModel;
    public OtherViewModel(IStatusBarViewModel statusBarViewModel)
    {
        _statusBarViewModel = statusBarViewModel;
    }
    public void UpdateTheDatabase()
    {
        _statusBarViewModel.StatusBarText = "Starting db update";
        // do some work here
        _statusBarViewModel.StatusBarText = "Db update complete";
    }        
}
```

}

Both VM's get the same status bar in their constructors and both are writing to the same status bar.  Both VM's take turns sharing the same region in your shell, "MainContentRegion".  Prism does all of this without the verbosity of this answer, but since you are in VB and do not use Prism, this approach will work fine.

Comment: Many thanks for sticking with me on this but I cannot even get the C# project to function the way I want. Since SO does not have private messaging, can I contact you directly through the email address on your site?

Comment: The c# I wrote above works fine.  You may need to hang back and downscale your design until you have a good prototype working.  And thanks for the offer to contact, but outside of SO, I earn a fee for this stuff and it's at the high end.  Try to work with what you've got and see how far you get.

Comment: Thanks, I was curious to see if you would send me your sample project where you had this working.

Comment: It's technically possible to send zip files, but massively at counterpoint to SO's practice and ethos because it puts the solution "off page"; but you've got working code and a great headstart.  At the moment, this question has gone as far as it can and you should either accept the best answer; or rescope the question; or if possible, get one of the higher ups to put a bounty on it.

Comment: So, to summaries this, you basically pass the StatusBar VM to every VM that needs to write to it right?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to achieve this in a nice clean way.

When using Prism or MvvmLight style frameworks, some kind of 'event aggregator' or 'messenger' class can be used to send messages between different parts of the application. Consider a view for the status bar, containing a text block and a progress bar. There would be a view model along the lines of this:

```
Class StatusViewModel
    Public Property Progress() As Integer
    ...
    Public Property Text() As String
    ...
End Class
```

Without having to create dependencies from everything to the StatusViewModel, we could use a shared service to send a message containing the information to change the progress or the text. For example

```
'progress changed to 75%
Messenger.SendMessage(Of ProgressChangedMessage)(New ProgressChangedMessage(75))
```

The `StatusViewModel` can then update its progress based on the inbound messages:

```
Messenger.[AddHandler](Of ProgressChangedMessage)(Function(message) 
    Me.Progess = message.NewProgress
End Function)
```

A second solution would be to share the StatusViewModel with every view model that wants to change the progress or status bar text. [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) or [Service Location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) makes this easy, but if you want to keep it simple you can use a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) instance to access the `StatusViewModel`.

When you expose the StatusViewModel to other classes it might be wise to use an interface, e.g:

```
Public Interface IStatusService
    Sub SetProgress(progress As Integer)
    Function SetText(text As String) As String
End Interface
```

edit: changed code to vb.

Comment: Thanks for the response, see my edits above. I am still unable to update the StatusBar text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Messages. Summary:

1. Your StatusBar VM listens to "UpdateStatusBar" messages
2. You send a message "UpdateStatusBar" with a string containing the message you want to write. This can be done from any part of your code (even outside VMs)

Messenger:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

//Messenger downloaded from StackOverflow and small modifications made
namespace GuitarDiary.Desktop.Utility
{
    public class Messenger
    {
        private static readonly object CreationLock = new object();
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<MessengerKey, object> Dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<MessengerKey, object>();

        #region Default property

        private static Messenger _instance;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the single instance of the Messenger.
        /// </summary>
        public static Messenger Default
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    lock (CreationLock)
                    {
                        if (_instance == null)
                        {
                            _instance = new Messenger();
                        }
                    }
                }

                return _instance;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the Messenger class.
        /// </summary>
        private Messenger()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers a recipient for a type of message T. The action parameter will be executed
        /// when a corresponding message is sent.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="recipient"></param>
        /// <param name="action"></param>
        public void Register<T>(object recipient, Action<T> action)
        {
            Register(recipient, action, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers a recipient for a type of message T and a matching context. The action parameter will be executed
        /// when a corresponding message is sent.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="recipient"></param>
        /// <param name="action"></param>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        public void Register<T>(object recipient, Action<T> action, object context)
        {
            var key = new MessengerKey(recipient, context);
            Dictionary.TryAdd(key, action);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Unregisters a messenger recipient completely. After this method is executed, the recipient will
        /// no longer receive any messages.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="recipient"></param>
        public void Unregister(object recipient)
        {
            Unregister(recipient, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Unregisters a messenger recipient with a matching context completely. After this method is executed, the recipient will
        /// no longer receive any messages.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="recipient"></param>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        public void Unregister(object recipient, object context)
        {
            object action;
            var key = new MessengerKey(recipient, context);
            Dictionary.TryRemove(key, out action);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a message to registered recipients. The message will reach all recipients that are
        /// registered for this message type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        public void Send<T>(T message)
        {
            Send(message, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a message to registered recipients. The message will reach all recipients that are
        /// registered for this message type and matching context.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        public void Send<T>(T message, object context)
        {
            IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<MessengerKey, object>> result;

            if (context == null)
            {
                // Get all recipients where the context is null.
                result = from r in Dictionary where r.Key.Context == null select r;
            }
            else
            {
                // Get all recipients where the context is matching.
                result = from r in Dictionary where r.Key.Context != null && r.Key.Context.Equals(context) select r;
            }

            foreach (var action in result.Select(x => x.Value).OfType<Action<T>>())
            {
                // Send the message to all recipients.
                action(message);
            }
        }

        protected class MessengerKey
        {
            public object Recipient { get; private set; }
            public object Context { get; private set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the MessengerKey class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="recipient"></param>
            /// <param name="context"></param>
            public MessengerKey(object recipient, object context)
            {
                Recipient = recipient;
                Context = context;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Determines whether the specified MessengerKey is equal to the current MessengerKey.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="other"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            protected bool Equals(MessengerKey other)
            {
                return Equals(Recipient, other.Recipient) && Equals(Context, other.Context);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Determines whether the specified MessengerKey is equal to the current MessengerKey.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="obj"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
                if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
                if (obj.GetType() != GetType()) return false;

                return Equals((MessengerKey)obj);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Serves as a hash function for a particular type. 
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                unchecked
                {
                    return ((Recipient != null ? Recipient.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^ (Context != null ? Context.GetHashCode() : 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

StatusBar VM:

```
public class StatusBarViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _statusBarText; 
    public string StatusBarText
    {
        get => _statusBarText;
        set
        {
            _statusBarText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StatusBarText));
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<UpdateStatusBar>(this, OnUpdateStatusBar);
    }

    private void OnUpdateStatusBar(UpdateStatusBar obj)
    {
        StatusBarText = obj.Text;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Message class:

```
public class UpdateStatusBar
{
    public UpdateStatusBar(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Send message to status bar:

```
StatusBarService.WriteToStatusBar($"Exercise '{Exercise.Name}' created");
```

XAML (make sure the view that contains this XAML is using StatusBar VM):

```
<StatusBar Background="SlateBlue"
           DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <StatusBarItem Content="{Binding StatusBarText}"></StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```

Answer (score -2):

Apply Singleton pattern for your statusbar object.

Comment: would you mind posting an example? I have tried applying a singleton pattern to the StatusBarViewModel class but I am still not able to get things working.